# how to import a class present inside a custom framework in swift

Tags: ios, frameworks, swift2

I have a custom frame work and it contains some public class.But i cannot able to use that public class.
In objective C we can import as

```
#import <XYZ/XYZCustomCell.h>
```

but how is  it possible in swift

Answer (score 7):

You import a module using the "import" keyword, it works the following way:

```
import XYZ
```

If you want to import a struct/function/enum only, you can do this:

```
import struct XYZ.SomeStruct
import func XYZ.someFunc
```

That syntax fits for typealias,  struct,  class, enum, protocol, var, or func.

Comment: i import the XYZ but unable to use the class inside the framework.These class are public classes and show in the header folder in the framework too

Answer (score 1):

It works also for classes, but the class that you try to import should be public :

```
public class DeviceHelper: NSObject {
}
```

And to use it, you just have to do :

```
import class DeviceHelper.DeviceHelper
```

with DeviceHelper that is a cocoa touch custom framework included in my project.