# Importing framework does add extra cost to the app in any sense, iOS, swift, Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, frameworks

**Let's Say I have following project hierarchy**

```
|-> Main App `import A, import B, import C`
|-> Framework A
|-> Framework B `import A`
|-> Framework C `import C`
|-> Framework D
```

- **Main App** uses most of the Frameworks. → ex : `import A, import B` in the app.
- Some other Frameworks use others. → `import A to use in Framework B`, `import A to use in Framework C`

> let's say I import **Framework A** to **Framework B** (`import A to Framework B` and `Framework C`) to just access from `Framework A` in
> `Framework B` and `Framework C`, does that mean it `Compiles` twice
> and **increase the app size** or just **Compile once** and link to
> both `Frameworks` **without increasing the app size**.

Hope your help and thoughts on this.

Comment: Instead of importing entire framework, you can import a speciffic class/struct/enum/func https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36002749/how-to-import-a-class-present-inside-a-custom-framework-in-swift

Comment: @mag_zbc thanks for the answer. what would be the benefit. Somehow we have to link the `framework` for this right?